# Writing down the formal homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Are $\mathbb N$ with topology $T$ - $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these, and $\mathbb N$ with topology $T'$- $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these homeomorphic?

Staring at the given topologies, the following emerges.

Consider $f: (\mathbb N, T') \to (\mathbb N, T)$.

Let $p > 2$ be prime.

Then $\displaystyle{f^{-1}\{2x + 1, 2x+ 2\} = \left\{\frac{p - 1}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}, \frac{(p+5) - 2}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}\right\} \in T' \implies \cup f^{-1}\{2x + 1, 2x+ 1\} \in T'}$ where $\cup$ is any union and so $f$ is continuous.

Now consider $g: (\mathbb N, T) \to (\mathbb N, T')$.

Then $\displaystyle{g^{-1}\left(\left\{\frac{p - 1}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}, \frac{(p+5) - 2}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}\right\}\right) = \{2x + 1, 2x+ 2\} \in T \implies \cup g^{-1}\left(\left\{\frac{p - 1}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}, \frac{(p+5) - 2}{2}_{\in \mathbb N}\right\}\right) \in T}$

where $\cup$ is any union and so $g$ is continuous.

But I am not sure how to define the rules $f(x), g(x)$ though. Consider $f(x) = \cases{2x + 1 \text{ if }x = \text{ bla } \\ 2x + 2 \text{ if }x = \text{ yada }}$. What goes in place of $\text{'bla' and 'yada'}?$ How do we write down the given rules formally? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply consider the bijection $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb N$ such that

- $f(1)=1$;
- $f(2)=3$;
- $f(3)=2$;
- $f(4)=4$;
- $f(5)=5$;
- $f(6)=7$;
- $\vdots$

That is, if $(a,b)$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> ordered pair from the list of pairs that defines $T$ and if $(a',b')$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> ordered pair from the list of pairs that defines $T'$, then $f(a)=a'$ and $f(b)=b'$.
It's clear that $f$ is a bijection and that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Comment: Do need to prove $f$ takes all $a, b$ to $a', b'$?

Comment: There is nothing to prove here. That's how I *defined* $f$.

Comment: To define $f$ that way you must be confident for every pair in $T$, there corresponds *only* one pair in $T'$. How do we know that? Does the permutation $1 \to 1, 2 \to 3, 3 \to 2, \ldots$ you outlined above guarantee that?

Comment: But $f$ maps the first ordered pair from the definition of $T$ into the first ordered pair from the definition of $T'$, it maps the first ordered pair from the definition of $T$ into the first ordered pair from the definition of $T'$, and so on. Where can yu possibly see a problem with that?